# View Update issue in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and trying to make a to-do list app. It is a simple app that uses local Storage to store data with the help of jStorage library.

When I add a task, the values get updated and the view appears, but it appears only once. The second time I add the data, it gets added to the localstorage but doesn't appears in the view. To get the view, I need to reload the page.

```
Controllers.taskController = function($scope, $compile, tasksFactory){
 $scope.tasksObjects = tasksFactory.getData();
 $scope.priority = 5;
 $scope.taskId = 0;
 $scope.addTask = function(){
    var objectToSend = {};
    objectToSend.title = $scope.task.title;
    objectToSend.description = $scope.task.description;
    objectToSend.priority = $scope.priority;
    objectToSend.priorityClass = priorityClassArray[($scope.priority - 1)];
    objectToSend.status = $scope.task.status;
    objectToSend.taskId = $scope.taskId++;

    tasksFactory.postData(objectToSend);
    if($scope.tasksObjects === null){
        $scope.tasksObjects = [];
    }
 }
};



angularApp.factory('tasksFactory', function(){
  var tasksFactory = {};

  tasksFactory.postData = function(ObjectToAdd){
    var existingData = $.jStorage.get('tasks');
    console.log(existingData);
    if(existingData === null){
        $.jStorage.set('tasks','[]');
        existingData =[];
    }
    existingData.push(ObjectToAdd);
    $.jStorage.set('tasks',existingData);
  };

  tasksFactory.getData = function(){
    return $.jStorage.get('tasks');
  }

  return tasksFactory;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider, at the end of addTask(), adding

```
$scope.tasksObjects = tasksFactory.getData();
```

I'm assuming that the view is referencing tasksObjects.

Comment: @Sadique - you probably want to check off the answer as "the answer" - that way other folks won't waste time reading the post, and I get points.